# Disable a WPF Border inside its MouseDown EventTrigger

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, border, eventtrigger

How can I **disable** a Border control when its MouseDown event is triggered. I have the following `XAML`, but the `Property Setter` is ***not*** allowed in `EventTrigger` and I am constrained to do this only in XAML:

```
<Border x:Name="border">
    <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType={x:Type Border}>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseDown">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <!--Setters not allowed in EventTriggers-->
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/> 
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers?
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Border x:Name="border">
  <Border.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseDown">
          <EventTrigger.Actions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
              <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.IsEnabled)">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                      <sys:Boolean>False</sys:Boolean>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                  </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
              </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
          </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Border.Style>
</Border>
```

We use a `Storyboard` to work around not being able to set a `Setter` directly and have the Animation instant for an immediate effect.

**Update:**

Download Link: [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/skpc0l4sk7i4c1f/WpfApplication22.rar)

**Another Update** (To show a different state for disabled on the `Border`)

```
<Border x:Name="border"
        BorderThickness="5">
  <Border.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
      <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="BurlyWood" />
      <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
            Value="Blue" />
      <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseDown">
          <EventTrigger.Actions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
              <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.IsEnabled)">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                      <sys:Boolean>False</sys:Boolean>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                  </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
              </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
          </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                  Value="False">
          <Setter Property="Background"
                  Value="Gray" />
          <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                  Value="DarkGray" />
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Border.Style>
  <Button Margin="100"
          Content="Some Button" />
</Border>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Have you tested the code, in my case the Border does not get disabled..

Comment: @VS1 Yes I did. I've edited my answer with a download link at the bottom. When you invoke the `MouseDown` on the `Border` in the example you can see the `Button` within it get disabled.

Comment: Thanks, did you type `Button` in above comment by mistake, will it disable the `Border` itself?

Comment: @VS1 no I did not. The `Border` by itself gives no Visual cue whether it's enabled or not by default. In the attached example I have a `Button` "inside" the `Border` which will get disabled since it's parent (our `Border`) got disabled due to the `EventTrigger`. You can setup a `Trigger` to be based on `IsEnabled="False"` on the `Border` and change it's `Background` or `BorderBrush` to get a visual cue from the `Border` when disabled. It just ain't default behavior. See the update I just made for an example of this.